# Deleting file versions except the latest version either using JSOM or SPServices

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, spservices

I want to write script that gets all versions of documents in site and deletes all of them except latest version either using CSOM or SPServices. I have found some information on net but could not find concrete method to delete. Guidance will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize [SP.FileVersionCollection.deleteAll Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244895.aspx) for that purpose:

**Example**

```
var fileName = '/sites/news/Pages/default.aspx';

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var versions = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileName).get_versions();
versions.deleteAll();
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function()
   { 
      console.log('File versions have been deleted');   
   },
   logError);


function logError(sender,args)
{
   console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: we need to write : ctx.load(versions) before ctx.executeQueryAsync correct ?

Comment: nope, there is no need to load versions since you are going to delete them

Comment: Does that mean load is only needed for select type of queries ?

Comment: For select mostly but also could be useful for update operations

Comment: ok thanks but here we updated versions but havent used load. Is there specific scenario when we need load and when we do not ?